# Send data from android to php

Tags: java, php, android

I need to help about to send data from android to php. I have this java code for android;

```
public void sendToDb()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pLat",Double.toString(lat)));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pLng",Double.toString(lng)));

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new      
                HttpPost("http://123456.com/welcome.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }           
}
```

and I have in my php folder this codes;

```
<?php
 $pLat = $_POST['pLat'];
 $pLng = $_POST['pLng'];

 $result = mysql_query("update Users set lat='$pLat',lon='$pLng' where username='ozi');      
 if (mysql_affected_rows()==0) 
   {
    $query = "INSERT INTO Users ";
    $query .= "(lat,lon) VALUES ('$pLat','$pLng')";
   }
 }
?>
```

When I send to data from my phone there is no problem but after I look mysql lat and lot rows not null but empty.
Is there a problem that you see in codes?

Comment: Try using `print_r($_POST);` in the PHP script to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? If you're refreshing from your browser, you will see an empty page... always.

Comment: @Vinnie I mean how can see these? I think it can be with ajax but I don't know script for this refresh automatic

Comment: Where are you trying to see them? In the android app? Or elsewhere?

Comment: @Vinnie I send a data from Android phone after I refresh the page on my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, what you're trying to do (I think) is persist data. The php file does nothing but run the code you have. The POST variables are only alive if you pass them in the request. The request is coming from the Android app along with POST variables and the response to the Android app will have the correct output.

The request coming from your browser is a "GET" and does not send a pLat or pLng variable, so there is no variables to output.

This is a very basic concept of HTTP that you must grasp.

What you are trying to do is save the data somewhere. PHP can do that by saving it to a database (such as MySQL) or by simply outputting the POST variables to a local file. A quick google search can show you how to save files and open databases. Heck, you can even just send them in an email to yourself.

The PHP script will only hold those variables for the life of the script and then release them out of memory forever. It's up to you to use the power of PHP to save those variables somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance I can already see some insanity here. Why do you specify `where username=  {   $_SESSION['username']}` when the call is coming from an android device? What session is there? Additionally, if this fails you insert with no username. but then never run the query.

```
 if (mysql_affected_rows()==0) 
   {
    $query = "INSERT INTO Users ";
    $query .= "(username, lat,lon) VALUES ('ozi', '$pLat','$pLng')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); // <---- this would need to be run
   }
 }
```

I suggest you fix those 2 very critical observations first, then update your question with a more targeted problem. Then I may update this answer to be more useful.

Comment: and I updated. Also, look into PDO. mysql_ is pretty much deprecated

Comment: Thank you for your answers. And what you think about last post ( link to old question) it was creative right ? :))

Comment: I think real reputation is never be virtual.

Comment: Well at any rate, did this help at all?

Comment: I tried but mysql didn't change then I tried with like that; $pLat="abc" $pLng="def" but it didn't work, so my php code have error I think , what's your suggestion about that?

Comment: lat and long should be floats. If you try passing strings it should error. check my update and see what error it produces

Comment: I can't believe that... it gived nothing I mean query didn't die..what about my data type ? in mysql my data type of plat and plng is varchar(40). Is it true ? I think it's true because I tried on plat="abc" plng="def"..

Comment: ok, well in that case it SHOULD have done something. But your lat and long should be floats anyhow. None the less, you can remove the variables and just plug in data. If nothing happens, check your mysql connection. Also try running the query manually in phpmyadmin. There's only so far we're able to go in these comments before we simply refer the OP to a tutorial. I suggest you switch to PDO before this gets too ugly. Google search it. It's easy to use.