# sql/php syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting

Tags: php, syntax

I got error on line 16 in myphp page which is;

```
$result = mysql_query("update Users set lat='$lat',lon='$lng' where username=$_SESSION['username']");
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: maybe you will be kind to tell us what the error is

Comment: @JasonMcCreary yes, another guy sad same thing to me.Whats your suggest PDO or Mysqli ?

Comment: If it's available, I say go with PDO.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary mymain problem [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608453/send-data-from-android-to-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lost track of all needed `'` and additionally forgot to quote username value. So instead of

```
$result = mysql_query("update Users set lat='$lat',lon='$lng' where username=$_SESSION['username']");
```

do this in more clean manner:

```
$result = mysql_query( "update Users set lat='$lat',lon='$lng' where username='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'");
```

or even better:

```
$query = sprintf("update Users set lat='%s',lon='%s' where username=%s"), 
         $lat, $lng, $_SESSION['username']);
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

BTW: switch to MYSQLi or PDO as MYSQL extension is **deprecated**, no new code should touch it.

Comment: `$query` is PHP variable containing your query to be executed and `sprint()` above is definitely PHP's

Comment: sql did not change :(  =>  [myquestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608453/send-data-from-android-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need curly braces `{}` inside of the string to return array parts:

```
$result = mysql_query("update Users set lat='$lat',lon='$lng' where username={$_SESSION['username']}");
```

**Note:** As has already been mentioned, you shouldn't be using `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 0):

Although mysql_* functions are being deprecated here is the error on your query:

```
$result = mysql_query("update Users set lat='$lat',lon='$lng' where username=".$_SESSION['username']);
```

Also make sure your inputs are sanitized before being used in your query:

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems, but the error relates to variable expansion with your [double quoted string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

**Error:**

```
echo "$_SESSION['username']";
```

**No Error:**

```
echo "{$_SESSION['username']}";
```

**Alternatives:**

```
echo "..." . $_SESSION['username'] . "...";
echo '...' . $_SESSION['username'] . '...';
```

Read the documentation on [Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to determine how you want do handle variable expansion in strings.

I'd also recommend reading about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).